# ElasticSearch Multi Field Terms Facet doesn't seem to work

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I'm trying to get the Multi-Field Terms Facet to work, but the results can't seem to do what the documentation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html#_multi_fields_2) is saying.

A bit about the setup and the queries I've tried:

I'm using ES 1.1.0:

```
"name": "William Baker",
    "version": {
        "number": "1.1.0",
     ...
    }
```

The mapping:

```
{
    "index_name": {
        "mappings": {
            "object": {
                "properties": {
                    "nested_object": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query JSON:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
                "match_all": {}
           }
        }
    },
    "facets": {
       "test4": {
          "terms": {
              "fields": ["nested_object.name", "nested_object.id"]
          },
          "nested": "nested_object"
       }
   }
}
```

The result:

```
"facets": {
      "test4": {
         "_type": "terms",
         "missing": 0,
         "total": 26,
         "other": 12,
         "terms": [
            {
               "term": "Port Anastasia College",
               "count": 3
            },
            {
               "term": "31",
               "count": 3
            },
            {
               "term": "Zorahaven College",
               "count": 1
            },
            {
               "term": "West Lonzoview College",
               "count": 1
            },
            ...
       ]
      }
}
```

I don't understand why the query is returning only the first ID, and as a separate term, instead of an aggregation of the two, as described in the documentation.

I'd appreciate any idea on how to get this multi-field facet to work.

Thanks.

Comment: You are using facets on two fields, what are you trying to achieve?